# Redis and huge amount of keys

Tags: php, lua, redis

I faced the need of speeding up my app (written in PHP, simple GET-service) and I decided to move it from RDBMS approach to Redis. Spending a week of researching on how to do this and considering that I have a lot of tables with a lot of fields in my relational database I made such structure in redis:
`{nameOfTable:clientID:itemID}`, for example

```
SET clientSubjects:1:1 bigJSONStringHere1
SET clientSubjects:1:2 bigJSONStringHere2
SET clientSubjects:1:3 bigJSONStringHere3

SET clientSubjects:2:1 bigJSONStringHere4
SET clientSubjects:2:2 bigJSONStringHere5
SET clientSubjects:2:3 bigJSONStringHere6
```

etc.

And I have about 20 million clients, each has about 4-10 subjects, so it's about 150 million keys.
To find all clients' subjects I have to use `SCAN` each time I get request from a certain client. I faced a problem that when I finished loading all clients to Redis, the command

`scan 0 match clientSubjects:{someID}:* count 100` returns:

```
1) "7241728"
2) (empty list or set)
```

And... My decision was to find total number of keys in redis storage and use it as `COUNT` argument.

This looks like:

```
local keyspace = redis.call("info", "keyspace")
local keysCount = keyspace:match("keys=(%d+),")
local result = redis.call("SCAN", 0, "match", "clientSubjects:" .. ARGV[1] .. ":*", "count", keysCount) --ARGV means I pass clientID to lua script
```

So everything works fine except that it needs about 3 seconds to execute! But I need it to be about few milliseconds... What can I do?

Comment: Dear Dasha, the question can be closed by many reasons, but out of curiosity, why redis? E.g. mongo should be quite good for this usecase.

Comment: @AlexBlex Because I need some cache system that will store data in memory

Comment: Fair enough. The most obvious advice is to check if it fits into memory,  check what is reported in slowlog, and ask how to solve exact problem. In general, it would be advisable to use sets to group subjects by client.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thank you. Can you please give an example of `use sets to group subjects by client` I can't understand you clearly(

Comment: I hardly can answer better than fire. May be just add a link to the docs https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets. But again, 3 seconds is way too much, even for 150m keys scan. The only explanation I can imagine is it swaps data to disk. Unfortunately your question is too wide, so the best answer you can get is a general advice like the one fire gave you.

Answer (score 1):

With 20 million records your going to require a huge amount of memory to store all of your data structures and the different ways to query it.

To find all clients' subjects for example, I would have a set or a list called `clientSubjects:{clientID}` with values of the subject ID.

You should have different data structures to suit your different queries and avoid using something like SCAN as this is not optimal.

In my opinion a relational database with some well placed indexes would be more suitable for this, it will save you a lot of time and money as indexes are usually held in memory and can fall back to disk.

Remember that Redis requires you to store all of your data in memory, so as you add more data structures to solve your different query types this is going to become more costly.